Build a typed HttpClient with AddHealthCheck on same class
I have a http's device that the application contact.
In first step, I have build around the IHttpFactory as preconised by Microsoft
        builder.Services.AddHttpClient<ISynchronicProvider, SynchronicProvider>(client =>
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri($"{builder.Configuration["Synchronic:protocol"]}://{builder.Configuration["Synchronic:host"]}:{builder.Configuration["Synchronic:port"]}");
            client.SetBasicAuthentication(builder.Configuration["Synchronic:user"], builder.Configuration["Synchronic:pass"]);
        });  

This is working well, extensible with Polly and Logger and used with simple function
        public async Task SendOpenP1Async() => await httpClient.GetAsync($"?E={telecommande.Emetteur}&T={telecommande.OpenP1}");

In next step, I have implemented health monitoring on this device like this
    public async Task<HealthCheckResult> CheckHealthAsync(HealthCheckContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        using var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
        httpClient.SetBasicAuthentication(synchronic.User, synchronic.Pass);

        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync($"{synchronic.Protocol}://{synchronic.Host}:{synchronic.Port}?E={telecommande.Emetteur}&T={telecommande.Status}", cancellationToken);

        return response.IsSuccessStatusCode ?
                        HealthCheckResult.Healthy($"Synchronic device is healthly") :
                        HealthCheckResult.Unhealthy("Synchronic device is unhealthy");
    }

and add the feature on Program.cs by this way
        builder.Services.AddHealthChecks()
                        .AddCheck<SynchronicHealthCheck>("Synchronic Health Check", failureStatus: HealthStatus.Unhealthy);

this is working like a charm
BUT
if I declare interfaces on same class like this
public class SynchronicProvider : ISynchronicProvider, IHealthCheck

and implement with injected HttpClient instead IHttpClientFactory
    public async Task<HealthCheckResult> CheckHealthAsync(HealthCheckContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync($"?E={telecommande.Emetteur}&T={telecommande.Status}", cancellationToken);

        return response.IsSuccessStatusCode ?
                        HealthCheckResult.Healthy($"Synchronic device is healthly") :          
                        HealthCheckResult.Unhealthy("Synchronic device is unhealthy");
    }

httpClient base url is empty for this method, but ever populated on another methods.
In Program.cs, I have tried to declare health feature before and after
        // Http factory
        builder.Services.AddHttpClient<ISynchronicProvider, SynchronicProvider>(client =>
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri($"{builder.Configuration["Synchronic:protocol"]}://{builder.Configuration["Synchronic:host"]}:{builder.Configuration["Synchronic:port"]}");
            client.SetBasicAuthentication(builder.Configuration["Synchronic:user"], builder.Configuration["Synchronic:pass"]);
        });

        // Health check
        builder.Services.AddHealthChecks()
                        .AddCheck<SynchronicProvider>("Synchronic Health Check", failureStatus: HealthStatus.Unhealthy);

So, why it is not working ?
I guess that dependancy injection from AddHttpClient that "take the lead", but I don't know not more.
Can you explain this, and / or resolve the issue ?
Thanks for helping

First, have you considered using the AspNetCore.HealthChecks.Uris health check instead of creating your own? There are a lot of ready-made healthchecks. Second, you don't show the code for your own healthcheck class. Where does it get the HttpClient or HttpClientFactory? Is the SynchronicProvider trying to act as both the typed HttpClient and the healthcheck ?

@PanagiotisKanavos "if I declare interfaces on same class like this
public class SynchronicProvider : ISynchronicProvider, IHealthCheck" I think that is exactly what OP is trying to do,  both typed client and check in one class.

@PanagiotisKanavos Yes, my need is to have inside SynchronicProvider both of implementation to retrieve a HttpClient well configured with Polly, Logger and Authorization layer. Thank you for the useful link, the CheckHealthAsync is currently simple, but other business rules will be added soon.

This morning, I have declared IHealthCheck as parent of ISynchronicProvider and declared the interface instead the class builder.Services.AddHealthChecks()                             .AddCheck<ISynchronicProvider>("Synchronic Health Check", failureStatus: HealthStatus.Unhealthy);and it is working well :)

In response of this use case, you can inherit interface IHealthCheck on IProvider and declare IProvider for HealthCheck binding.
Then, in implementation class, you have the both implementation and especially a well configured HttpClient.
//interface declaration
        public interface ISynchronicProvider : IHealthCheck { ... } 

// binding HealthCheck on interface
        builder.Services.AddHealthChecks()
                        .AddCheck<ISynchronicProvider>("Synchronic Health Check", failureStatus: HealthStatus.Unhealthy); 

// httpClient is working in both impl.
        public async Task SendStatusAsync() => await httpClient.GetAsync($"?E={telecommande.Emetteur}&T={telecommande.Status}");

        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78794475/build-a-typed-httpclient-with-addhealthcheck-on-same-class
        public async Task<HealthCheckResult> CheckHealthAsync(HealthCheckContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
          var response = await httpClient.GetAsync($"?E={telecommande.Emetteur}&T={telecommande.Status}", cancellationToken);

            return response.IsSuccessStatusCode ?
                            HealthCheckResult.Healthy($"Synchronic device is healthly") :
                            HealthCheckResult.Unhealthy("Synchronic device is unhealthy");
        }

